# How to add extra library in ML FLOW which can not be added through conda.yaml

Tags: mlflow

It would be great if you can shed some light.

I m building a data science project using MLFLOW. I can install most of library through conda.yaml. But there is one library which is in azure artifact. which can not be packaged directly. Is there any way we can mention extra libraries for MLFLOW when we run it on databricks/Locally. Which MLFLOW can use it while running